# BashScript: Read a file and process it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, terminal

I have a file with this structure:

```
Text...
        A                          B                    C
        A1                   57,624,609,830           20.99
        A2                   49,837,119,260           20.90
        A3                      839,812,303           20.88
        A4                      843,568,192           20.87
        ...                   1,016,104,564           20.82
        A29                   1,364,178,406           16.62
 A line of text
 Blank
 Text
 Text
        A                          B                    C
        A1                   57,624,609,830           20.99
        A2                   49,837,119,260           20.90
        A3                      839,812,303           20.88
        A4                      843,568,192           20.87
        ...                   1,016,104,564           20.82
        A29                   1,364,178,406           16.62
```

and I want to get all the A1s with it's values, then all the A2s with its values and so on.
What I'm doing so far is

```
cat myFile.csv | awk '{if (NR > 5 && NR <= 29) printf $1"\t"}' > tmp1.csv
```

I get the A1    A2    A3... in different cells in a new file tmp1.csv
and then

```
cat myFile.csv | grep A1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

to get tthe values of A1, copy paste to the column A1 in tmp1 file.
I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
input="myFile.csv"
while IFS= read -r line

do

    awk '{if (NR > 4 && NR <= 28) | grep A1 | awk print $2 }'

done < "$input"
```

but cannot make it to produce the same result as

```
      A1                 A2                 A3              A4        ... 
57,624,609,830     49,837,119,260      839,812,303      839,812,303   ...
57,624,609,830     49,837,119,260      839,812,303      839,812,303   ...
...
```

in a file. In other words it would be ideal for me to get from the 5th to the 28th line the $1 in different cells and their $2 in each column accordingly.

**UPDATE**

```
cat myFile.csv | awk '{if (NR > 5 && NR <= 29) printf $1"\t"}'
```

gives me the the content of the lines I care about. How can I loop into the entire file, in all lines to get all the contents? For instance instead of

`NR>5 && NR<=29` to have x=1
`NR>x+4 && NR<=x+28` and eventually get the content.

Comment: Everything you're trying to do with `cat ... | grep ... | awk ...` can just be done with awk alone. `awk` is a full-fledged programming language; consider using it as such -- and `cat`'s purpose is **concatenating** files; if you're using it to read from just one file, `foo <filename` [which just runs the command `foo` with a direct, seekable handle on `filename`] is far more efficient than `cat filename | foo` [which runs a copy of `/usr/bin/cat`, and a copy of `foo`, with a `mkpipe`-based FIFO between them].

Comment: ...frankly, running awk alone -- no bash, no grep -- is probably the Right Thing here.

Comment: Why aren't you doing something like `awk '$1~/^A[0-9]+/ {# here is a line of AXX data...}'`

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/A[0-9]+/' file | sed -r 's/^ +//g' | sort -k1.1,1.1 -k1.2n

A1                   57,624,609,830           20.99
A1                   57,624,609,830           20.99
A2                   49,837,119,260           20.90
A2                   49,837,119,260           20.90
A3                      839,812,303           20.88
A3                      839,812,303           20.88
A4                      843,568,192           20.87
A4                      843,568,192           20.87
A29                   1,364,178,406           16.62
A29                   1,364,178,406           16.62
```

or if your `sort` supports version sort, it will work too.  You can restrict pattern match perhaps with adding `&& NF==3`

If you need to transpose layout, you can pipe the output of the first script to

```
$ ... | awk 'NR%2{h=h FS $1; r1=r1 FS $2} !(NR%2){r2=r2 FS $2}
              END{print h; print r1; print r2}' | column -t

A1              A2              A3           A4           A29
57,624,609,830  49,837,119,260  839,812,303  843,568,192  1,364,178,406
57,624,609,830  49,837,119,260  839,812,303  843,568,192  1,364,178,406
```

or combine both into a single script, especially if your records are already sorted.

**UPDATE**

Combined script starting from the original input file

```
$ awk '/A[0-9]+/ && NF==3{if (!a[$1]++) {h=h FS $1; r1=r1 FS $2} else {r2=r2 FS $2}}
                      END{print h; print r1; print r2}' file | 
  column -t

A1              A2              A3           A4           A29
57,624,609,830  49,837,119,260  839,812,303  843,568,192  1,364,178,406
57,624,609,830  49,837,119,260  839,812,303  843,568,192  1,364,178,406
```

Comment: Thank you karafka for you answer but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I updated my question to be more accurate.

Comment: no problem, I usually try to extrapolate from what I read.  See the update.

Comment: karafka when I use just the last command in the console (awk '/A[0-9]+/ && NF==3{if (!a[$1]++) {h=h FS $1; r1=r1 FS $2} else {r2=r2 FS $2}}
                      END{print h; print r1; print r2}' myFile.csv | 
  column -t) does nothing. If I remove the '/A[0-9]+/ && it outputs the result but not in columns. I can see that clearer when I do > output.csv in Excel in which all the values are in the first two rows.

Comment: perhaps you have more fields, please remove `&& NF==3`.  It works with the data file you posted though.